# Make jenkins send email via sendmail

Tags: jenkins, sendmail

I got a `nullmailer` setup to a 3rd party SMTP relay. It's working well.

**How can I tell jenkins to send his email through the `sendmail` system function** ?

I tried setting the SMTP credentials directly in jenkins, but it's a mess with TLS (none of the solution I tried worked with Mandrill)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I run into this problem today. If you don't want to setup a smtp provider such as gmail, you can install **postfix** (see [here](https://serverfault.com/a/144010) about how to install postfix non-interactively) on the maschine/container on which Jenkins is running.

Make sure postfix runs well. In my case postfix did not start automatically after installation.

```
service postfix start
```

Then in Jenkins select **Manage Jenkins => Configure System => Email Notification**. Enter **localhost** In field "SMTP Server". Let Jenkins send out a test mail to test it.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not possible. Without looking at the Jenkins source (you can check this for yourself), I'd almost expect (no, hope!) that Jenkins would simply use the `javax.mail.*` interface, which only supports SMTP, and not command-line interfaces to MTAs.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure that sendmail is a really system function. But if you want to send jenkins notifications through smtp you need install https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin and configure connection in global jenkins configuration.